# How to increment the properties of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a table that is populated from an arraylist that can vary in size, depending on user input. I need to create a new instance of "existingStrings" on each iteration of the array. At the moment only the last value ("c" for i=2) is being displayed, which is what I would expect for what I have done below. The problem that I have is how can I create a new instance of "existingString" on each iteration so that the object (this.collection) contains the attribute "existingStrings" 3 times (once for each element of the array).

```
this.stringList=["a","b","c"];


for (var i=0; i<this.stringList.length; i++){
        this.collection = [  
            {"existingStrings": this.stringList[i]},
        ];
        }
```

I would like this.collection to end up like this below:

```
this.collection=[{"existingStrings":"a"},
                 {"existingStrings":"b"},
                 {"existingStrings":"c"}]"
```

Comment: do you want this.collection like `"[{"existingStrings":"a"},{"existingStrings":"b"},{"existingStrings":"c"}]"`

Comment: yes-that's exactly what i want. sorry if that wasn't clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var stringList=["a","b","c"];
this.collection = []

for (var i=0; i<this.stringList.length; i++){
        this.collection.push({"existingStrings": this.stringList[i]});
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to push, the results in the collection and not override them

```
var stringList=["a","b","c"];
var collection = []
for (var i=0; i<stringList.length; i++){
    collection.push({"existingStrings": stringList[i]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but you could `push` the object to `this.collection`:

```
var stringList = ["a","b","c"];

stringList.forEach(function(item) {
    if(!this.collection) {
        this.collection = [];
    }

    this.collection.push({"existingStrings": item});
});
```

This would leave you with the output (the content of `this.collection`):

```
[{"existingStrings": "a"}, {"existingStrings": "b"}, {"existingStrings": "c"}]
```

Comment: `this.collection` is undefined.

Comment: I fixed my code to account for `this.collection` being `undefined`.

Comment: I think it's better to declare `[]` in starting, rather checking every time in loop.

Comment: That would really depend on the given situation. It is less efficient to check every loop, but in some cases it might be necessary.